# How to read date & time from a text file ,and compare the data in C#

Tags: c#

Please help me to compare the date and time in the two text files , and compare to check if they are the same, using `DateTime.TryParse` method or any other method.

I have the following code:

```
        String[] file1Lines = File.ReadAllLines("Text.txt");
        String[] file2Lines = File.ReadAllLines("Text2.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(file1Lines.Length, file2Lines.Length); i++)
        {
            if (i > file1Lines.Length)
                /* missing from file 1 */
                Console.WriteLine("Missing from File 1");
            else if (i > file2Lines.Length)
                /* missing from file 2); */
               Console.WriteLine("Missing from File 1") ;
            else if (file1Lines[i].Equals(file2Lines[i]))
                /* lines are equal */
               Console.WriteLine("Lines are equal") ;
            else
                /* lines are different */

                Console.WriteLine("Lines are different");
        }
```

Comment: what's preventing you fixing your code?

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you have?  You are comparing lines for equality between two files - is the problem that you want to convert each line to a `DateTime` before comparison?  Have you tried any code that has failed to work?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Missing from File 1")` should be `File 2` the 2nd time, no?

Comment: The two text files , Text.txt and Text2.txt , can be assumed to be log files which contain date and time in this format :2013-05-07 13:57 . Now both the text files contain similar data , and I have to compare this data to check if they are the same . I am new to C# coding , hence the doubts .

Comment: THnks Moo Juice , I will correct that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you need something like below:

```
    String[] file1Lines = File.ReadAllLines("Text.txt");
    String[] file2Lines = File.ReadAllLines("Text2.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(file1Lines.Length, file2Lines.Length); i++)
    {
        if (i > file1Lines.Length)
            /* missing from file 1 */
            Console.WriteLine("Missing from File 1");
        else if (i > file2Lines.Length)
            /* missing from file 2); */
           Console.WriteLine("Missing from File 1") ;
        else {
            DateTime file1Date = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime file2Date = DateTime.Now;
                            // try parse a line from first file
            if(DateTime.TryParse(file1Lines[i], out file1Date)) {
                                  // try parse a line from second file
                if( DateTime.TryParse(file2Lines[i], out file2Date)) {
                    if (file1Date.Date == file2Date.Date) {
                        /* lines are equal */
                        Console.WriteLine("Dates are equal") ;
                    } else {
                        /* lines are different */
                        Console.WriteLine("Dates are different");
                    }
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Line in file 2 is not a date") ;
                }                   
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Line in file 1 is not a date") ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: THank you , let me try this .

Comment: I just check it out . It works if the date and time are the same in both the files . Suppose in File 1 the data is : 20-06-2013 5:45           and in the second line i have 21-06-2013 6:45 , and in the second file I have 20-06-2013 5:45 and second line I have 21-06-2013 7:34, the output I get is Dates are equal /n Dates are different .

Comment: Oh. You need to check dates only! Second..

Comment: See updated answer. `if (file1Date == file2Date) {` is replaced with `if (file1Date.Date == file2Date.Date) {` Now it will check dates only and will ignore time.